# Keycloak development instance: broken authentication configuration

Tags: keycloak

I'm running a local h2 based development instance of keycloak (quarks one). I've been trying to add another custom means of login and I seem to have broken it.

I've changed the `First Broker Login Flow` and disabled the `Review Profile(review profile config)`. I cannot login anymore. I get his error in the keycloak instance console when going into the login screen:

```
    WARN  [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (executor-thread-12) REQUIRED and ALTERNATIVE elements at same level! Those alternative executions will be ignored: [auth-cookie, null]
2022-09-25 10:50:38,131 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-12) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException
```

Is there a way to revert this change through some config file / h2? Or do I just have to delete keycloak and start from scratch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to reproduce your problem from scratch for local h2 based Keycloak? Please read this [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete h2 related files from `data/h2` directory. Though you will lose the configuration which you have done.

Comment: If this is a in memory db, then perhaps I can just alter the tables in a way that it may start to work :)

Comment: Yes you can. But I would suggest you use some persistent database instead of h2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using some external ID provider with OpenID/SAML

Set a display name for your ID provider configuration
In Identity Provider Redirector configuration, use that display name as alias name.
Make it required
Then it will work fine.

I was experiencing the same issue, resolved by doing this.